# Issue importing another class in the same directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm trying to import a class `Parser` from a file `parser.py` in the same directory. However I keep getting the following error whenever I try to instantiate a Parser object:

```
File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
   from parser import Parser
ImportError: cannot import name Parser
```

I'm instantiating the object in the following way:

```
parser = Parser();
```

The same script works at my friend's setup so I'm not sure if it's a problem with the code. my version of python is 2.7.13. I'm including the imports below:

`bot.py`:

```
from parser import Parser

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging
import csv
import os, sys, types
from random import randint
import urllib2
import json
import string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

`parser.py:`

```
 import re

 class Parser: 
   .....
      ##parser stufff
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try passing a relative path like

```
from .parser import Parser
```